# how to scrape my cloudflare protected site using oxylabs proxies?

Tags: flask, web-scraping, python-requests, cloudflare

We have a flask app that uses the WP rest api endpoints of 3 of our WordPress sites.
Basically, We usually make get requests using python's **requests** library to some custom endpoints that we added to the WordPress sites.

The app was running fine until we added cloudflare protection and **enabled attack mode**. Now we cannot make any requests, cloudflare rejects with 403 status code. I've used Oxylabs proxies even, still doesn't work.
However, in one of the sites attack mode is not enabled and the app works fine for that one.

How can I make the app work on the sites where **attack mode** is enabled with the requests library using proxies and user-agents?